# Are indexes on the join table used in many-to-many relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, indexing, many-to-many

Say I have a database with 3 tables describing bus timetables:

```
journey
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start        | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end          | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| route_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

operating_days
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start_date | date    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

journey_operating_days
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| journey_id          | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| operating_days_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If I do a query on this database, where I select a `journey` by `journey.id` and join in all the related fields from `operating_days` and order by `operating_days.start_date`, would an index on column `operating_days.start_date` be used to order them or would it be unusable for the db engine?

This is concerning MySQL and/or PostgreSQL engines.

Comment: Difficult to tell, as it depends on; which RDBMS (MySQL vs PostgreSQL), which _version_ of each, how many rows in each table, what the actual query is (join conditions, conditions in the `WHERE` clause, what data is in the `SELECT`...), what other queries are being run on the system, some of the physical storage realities... In general though, a index _starting_ with `operating_days.start_date` (then followed by one of the ids) will be useful for some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, for postgresql, is **it depends**.

The query optimizer is constantly worked on, and the execution plan depends on table size, selectivity of your where clauses, and many other factors.

Often people find: they create an index, and it is not used in queries. Reason: a sequential scan can be cheaper for the database than accessing the index, and then the data.

Query optimization is the subject of dedicated mailing lists.

Answer (score -1):

This is a sql related answer, not specific to any RDBMS. An Index is primarely used to get data in/out of memory quickly(by storing information on the location of the data in the file system). Ordering (usually) takes place after all data has been pulled, so NO an index in most cases will not be used when you are ordering/sorting your data. Because it already has been pulled out of the database.

Comment: Well usually if I had a composite index on `operating_days.start_date` and `operating_days.end_date` and had a query `SELECT * FROM operating_days WHERE start_date = 2014-01-01 ORDER BY end_date` it would use the index to order the pulled entries by end_date in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: -1 - False.  Optimizers _can_ (and do, when possible) use indices for ordering (and grouping, and a bunch of other things).  This depends somewhat on which RDBMS, but pretty much all of them can/will (different ones just use them to a different extent).